# Analytical solution of a non-linear equation with a 'min' function

Tags: real-analysis, nonlinear-system

I am building a mathematical model of a non-linear dynamical system and I have an expression of this form:

$$x=\min\left(\frac{y}{a+y},\frac{y}{c+y(d+ex)}\right)$$

or let's consider any form like:

$$x=\min\big(f(x),g(x)\big)$$

How to solve this equation, considering that the individual equations $x=f(x)$ and $x=g(x)$ can be solved?

Should I solve $x=f(x)$ and $x=g(x)$ individually and choose the solution with minimum value?

Comment: No. Let $x_0$ be the smallest among the solutions of $x=f(x)\lor x=g(x)$, and assume that $f$ achieves it ($x_0=f(x_0)$. Still, you can very well have $f(x_0)>g(x_0)$ and $x_0\ne\min(f(x_0),g(x_0))$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I thought so but I am not sure how to solve this. Can you give me some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain all solutions $F_i$ of $x=f(x)$ and $G_j$ of $x=g(x)$.

Then the solutions of $x=\min(f(x),g(x))$ are all the $F_i$ such that $F_i\le g(F_i)$ and all the $G_j$ such that $G_j\le f(G_j)$, if any.

Comment: Just a stupid doubt: what if there was a constant ($a$) instead of $g(x)$? Would the solutions be all $F_i\le a$ and $a$ if it is $\le f(a)$ ?

Comment: @WYSIWYG: you get it $g(x)=a$ is also a function.

Comment: However, the nature of the system is such that multiple solutions cannot exist. So $a$ and $F_i$ have to be mutually exclusive. I think I have to prove (for this system) that when $F_i\le a$ then $a\gt f(a)$. The two functions are of the form described first in the question.